# Event to know when content of a directive has changed

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm creating a directive which position children div justify and with a margin = 0 changing the height of the children div. (like http://brunjo.github.io/rowGrid.js/)

All is working well. Except when the children are changing.

I have added a watch for the number of children so that if I add a child, it is still working.

But how to watch at the size of each child to update the layout when they are changing? Put a watch on each one of them?

Here is a plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/OYZ1snIjmLS4HRB6J5vy?p=preview

I'm new to angular, it may be an easy answer.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you please provide plunker or jsfiddle for us?

Comment: I've added a plunker.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**NOTICE:**
Watch expressions (e.g. the first argument of a `$watch()` function call) are executed several times per $digest cycle. Therefore, they should be kept as quick as possible. If your element has many children, it might become expensive to calculate all their widths.

If that is the case, it might be better to capture the events that are associated with the resizing of the children and check the sizes only when there is indeed the possibility that something got resized.

---

That said, you could do something like this:

```
$scope.$watchCollection(function() {
    return [].map.call(el[0].children, function (child) {
        return child.offsetWidth;
    });
}, function(newValue, oldValue) {  // Note: newValue comes before oldValue
    if (oldValue !== newValue) {
        console.log('eoke');
        this.layout(el, 'blue');
    }
}.bind(this));
```

See, also, this **[short demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/K2oZAQEJzz34ri2OL3cH?p=preview)**.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. There could be a lot of children (hundreds). With the event, how can you manage that? With the isolated scope, is it possible to listen to an event? Or how to dispatch an event on the scope of the directive?

Comment: You can $emit() and $broadcast() events but it depends on the implementation. The main question is what triggers an element's resizing ?

Comment: The idea would be to create a custom event and add an option in the directive: either you watch the size or you use event to say to the directive that the content has changed. But with a isolated scope, I don't know how to emit an event into the directive.

Comment: There are several way. You can use the $rootScope from both places (emitting & listening). But you still don't answer my question: What triggers an element's resizing ?

Comment: I don't think there is one. That's why I spoke about a custom event.Rootscope means I can't have two directives which refresh not together... Is there an other way to handle that?

Comment: 1.) Why can't you have two directives ? 2.) If there is nothing that causes the elements to resize, then they won't resize. I believe you are approaching the problem in the wrong way.

Comment: Finally, I have used watchCollection. I have indeed a problem of performance... but it is because of width() function of jquery! Which seems to be a know problem. I'll deal with that later, I have to go on! Thanks for your help.